# My layout gets messed up when zoomed out

Tags: html, alignment, gets

I started learn webdesign one week ago. I'm trying to create a webpage with three divs next to each other. My layout gets messed up when zoomed out. 50% zoom level is okay but when I started to zoom further right sidebar goes under the content div. please help :(

```
<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="banner">
    </div>

    <div id="topnav">
    </div>

    <div id="leftsidebar1">
    </div>

    <div id="content">
    </div>

    <div id="rightsidebar1">
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
    </div>

</div>


here's the css

    #wrapper{
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px 0 0 0;
    max-height:1000px;  
}

    #banner{
width:900px;
height:150px;
background-color: #000;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
border-top-left-radius: 10px;
border-top-right-radius: 10px;
```

}

```
#leftsidebar1{
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    height: 500px;
    background-color:#000;
}

#content{
    display:inline;
    width: 50%;
    height: 500px;
    background-color:#006;
    float:left;
}

#rightsidebar1{
    float:left;
    width: 25%;
    height:500px;
    background-color:#999;
}
```

Comment: Elements with the float attribute get rearranged when they don't fit.  I guess that's your case.

Answer (score 0):

Get three divs inside a parent div and set its size to total size of your three floating divs.